# setContent in SherlockFragment

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, fragment

in my class Lebanon i have this class:

```
class TabFactory implements TabContentFactory {

        private final Context mContext;

        public TabFactory(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            View v = new View(mContext);
            v.setMinimumWidth(0);
            v.setMinimumHeight(0);
            return v;
        }

    }
```

and here's the error:

```
private static void AddTab(
        SherlockFragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost,
        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));
```

Here actually i'm having this error:

```
SherlockFragmentActivity.TabFactory cannot be resolved to a type
```

I know this method work in SherlockFragmentActivity, but how does it work in SherlockFragment?!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your class `Lebanon` extends `SherlockFragmentActivity`?

If so, the reason you are getting the class error is because the type of `activity` passed in to `AddTab()` is a `SherlockFragmentActivty`. The compiler doesn't know you are actually passing a instance of `Lebanon` and therefore can't resolve the nested class `TabFactory`. Hence the error!

There are two solutions. First you can modify the `AddTab()` signature to take the subclass, e.g.

```
private static void AddTab(
    Lebanon activity, TabHost tabHost,
    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) {

    tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));

    // ... other code
}
```

The alternative is to keep the signature the same but add a cast to the the activity, i.e.

```
tabSpec.setContent(((Lebanon) activity).new TabFactory(activity));
```

The first solution is obviously much simpler and wont risk throwing a `ClassCastException` at runtime, so choose that if you can.

Comment: I'm extending SherlockFragment not sherlockFragmentActivity. the above code i posted works fine for sherlockFragmentActivity (your 1st solution is identical to the one i posted)

Comment: Ok... so if your class `Lebanon` extends `SherlockFragment*, what do you want to pass into `AddTab()`? And no, my 1st solution is different to your code. Check the parameter types.